# Patterns when designing REST POST endpoint when resource has a computed property

Tags: api, rest, oop, design-patterns

I have a resource, as an example a '**book**'.

I want to create a REST POST endpoint to allow consumers to create a new book.

However, some of the properties are **required** and **computed** by API, and others were actually taken as they are

```
Book
{
  name,
  color,
  author # computed
}
```

Let's say the **author** is somehow calculated in API based on the book name.

I can think of these solutions each has its drawbacks:

- enforce consumer to provide the author and just filter it (do not take into account as an input) # bad because it is very unpredictable why the author was changed
- allow the user to provide author # same problem
- do not allow the user to provide an author and show an exception if the user provides it

The last solution seems to be the most obvious one. The main problem I can see is that it is inconsistent and can be bizarre for consumers to see the author later on GET request.

I want my POST endpoint to be as expressive as possible. So the POST and GET data transfer objects will look almost the same.

Are there any simple, expressive, and predictable patterns to consider?

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'm a big fan of using the same format for a `GET` request as well as a `PUT`.

This makes it possible for a client to do a `GET` request, add a property to the object they received and immediately `PUT` again. If your API and clients follow this pattern, it also means it can easily add new properties to `GET` requests and not break clients.

However, while this is a nice pattern I don't really think that same expectation exists at much for 'creation'. There's usually many things that make less less to require as a property when creating new items (think 'id' for example), so I usually:

1. Define a schema for `PUT` and `GET`.
2. Define a separate schema for `POST` that only contains the relevant properties for creation.
3. If users supply properties not in the schema, always error with a `422`.

Answer (score 0):

> some of the properties are required and computed by API

Computed properties are neither required nor optional, by definition. No reason to ask consumers to pass such properties.

> do not allow the user to provide an author and show an exception if the user provides it

Indeed, DTO should not contain author-property. Consumers can send over network whatever they want, however it is the responsibility of the API-provider to publish contract (DTO) for consumers to use properly. API-provider controls over what properties to consider, and no exception should be thrown, as the number of "bad" properties that can be sent by consumers is endless.

> So the POST and GET data transfer objects will look almost the same

Making DTOs of the same resource look the same is not a goal. In many cases, get-operation exposes a lot more properties than post-operation for the same resource, especially when designing domain-driven APIs.

> Are there any simple, expressive, and predictable patterns to consider?

If you want your API to express the fact that author is computed, you can have the following endpoints:

POST http://.../author-computed-books

GET  http://.../books/1

Personally, I wouldn't implement that way since it does not look natural, however you can get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

> I want my POST endpoint to be as expressive as possible. So the POST
> and GET data transfer objects will look almost the same.

Maybe just document it instead of relying explicit stuff like it must be almost the same as the GET endpoint.

E.g. my POST endpoint is `POST /number "1011"` and my GET endpoint is `GET /number -> 11`. If I don't document that I expect binary and I serve decimal, then nobody will know and they would guess for example decimal for both. Beyond documentation another way of doing this and to be more explicit is changing the response for GET to include the base `{"base":10, value:"11"}` or changing the GET endpoint `GET /number/decimal -> 11`.

As of the computed author I don't understand how you would compute it. I mean either a book is registered and the consumer shouldn't register it again or you don't know much about the author of it. If the latter, then you can guess e.g. based on google results for the title, but it will be a guess, not necessarily true. The same with consumer data, but at least that is what the consumers provided. There is no certainty. So for me it would be a complex property not just a primitive one if the source of the information matters. Something like `"author": {name: "John Wayne", "source": "consumer/service"}` normally it is complex too, because authors tend to have ids, names, other books, etc.

Another thought that if it is weird for the consumers instead of expected, then I have no idea why it is a feature at all. If author guessing is a service, then a possible solution is making the property mandatory and adding a guessing service `GET /author?by-book-name={book-name}`, so they can use the service if they want to. Or the same with a completely optional property. This way you give back the control to the consumers on whether they want to use this service or not.